# Setting a FormArray to an array of FormGroups

Tags: angular

How can I set a FormArray of a FormGroup? I want to set `definitionProperties` (FormArray) of my form.

```
this.processorForm = this.fb.group({
    propertiesSide: new FormControl(),
    objectNamesSide: new FormControl(),
    definitionProperties: this.fb.array([])
});
```

The FormArray of FormGroups:

```
let propertyControls: FormGroup[] = [];
propertyControls = getFormGroups(); // set definitionProperties to this
```

I found some code to add one by one but I'd like to set with an array rather than one value using push if it's possible:

```
(this.gridProcessorForm.get('definitionProperties') as FormArray).push(group)
```

The `getFormGroups()` function builds an array of groups:

```
createPropertyFormGroup(definitionProperty: ObjectDefinitionProperty) {
   let formGroup = this.fb.group({
      propertyName: definitionProperty.name,
      propertyType: definitionProperty.type.name,
      gridOffset: 1
   });
   return formGroup;
}
```

The setting of the FormArray is in an observable:

```
this.gridProcessorForm.valueChanges.subscribe(...)
```

Comment: can't use in the declaration, getFormGroups() is used after another control is used

Comment: Can you explain it a bit more? I didn't get what you're trying to do.

Comment: @developer033 I need to do something like this processorForm.get('definitionProperties').set(newValue); I also need to make sure the valueChanges() event isn't triggered when setting the new value.

Comment: @doe, an array of FormGroups are not the same that a FormArray of FormGroups. Your function `createPropertyFormGroup` return a FormGroup. I must supouse you has an array of objects `[{name:'...',..},{name:'...',..}...]` you can map the array: `definitionProperties: this.fb.array(this.mydata.map(x=>this.createPropertyFormGroup(x))`, but really I'm not very sure about your question

Answer (score 1):

Try this for initial Setup

```
this.processorForm = this.fb.group({
    propertiesSide: new FormControl(),
    objectNamesSide: new FormControl(),
    definitionProperties: this.fb.array([
         this.fb.group({
             propertyName: definitionProperty.name,
             propertyType: definitionProperty.type.name,
             gridOffset: 1
         })
   })])
});
```

Use this for Adding more:

```
 var _definitionProperties= <FormArray>this.processorForm .controls.definitionProperties;
_definitionProperties.push({
       this.fb.group({
             propertyName: 'Name',
             propertyType: 'Type',
             gridOffset: 1
         })
 })
```

For more info read this:
https://medium.com/@m.kunwa52/reactive-form-in-angular-with-formarray-2595e5ee1d31